# coding onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

hello
i need to load page based on the results of dropdown box. for example in my code i have value="userlog". if this selected it will load userlog.php and remove itself so that only userlog.php is being used. thanks

```
<select onchange="updatePage(this.value)">

            <option value="">Select a report</option>
            <option value="userlog">User Logs</option>
            <option value="actionlog">Action Logs</option>

        </select>
```

Comment: I have a project to work on. Can you code it for me?

Comment: This is not a place to get people to write code for you. This is a place to get help when you get stuck.

Comment: brian.i have code that i saw here so thought i would try myself, but being a noob i did get stuck. cheers

Comment: @mcgrailm if a question has been answered correctly i accept it. thought that was the idea. i always thank people for there help and guidance.

Comment: @the_asman. no-one to code anything for me. i was just looking form guidance or perhaps someone knew of a good tut that they could recommend. this is not a project this is a learning curve. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select id="select_page">
  <option value="">Select a report</option>
  <option value="userlog">User Logs</option>
  <option value="actionlog">Action Logs</option>
</select>

$('#select_page').change(function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  if($el.val() != '') {
    $('#page').load($el.val()+'.php');
    $el.find('option:selected').remove();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On change event you will get the selected options value. Using this value you can decide what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

something like this :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("select option ").each(function() {

        if (location.href.indexOf($(this).val()) >= 0) {
            $(this).remove();
        }

    });


    $('select').change(function() {
        var obj = $(this);

        location.href = obj.val() + ".php";


    });

});
```